# Eclipse: How to automate export unsigned application in a batch file

Tags: android, eclipse, batch-file

I am developing a game for Android in Windows Vista environment. I want to automate the exporting unsigned application operation in a batch file. So, I wouldn't have to Right click on the project, go to Android Tools and then select Export Unsigned Application Package... anytime I want to run my project. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's Eclipse SDK just use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) behind the scenes for exporting application packages. You could just write an ANT build file and do the export you are trying to, and you will have yourself the task on a batch file.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a nice link: http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html, written by Matt Quigley.

In a nutshell:

You create a build.xml file by going to the root path and entering `android update project --path .`.

This will create a build.xml file. From that point on, you should be able to build an unsigned apk by running `ant release`.